# how to implement multiprocessing in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, web-worker

I want to implement multiprocessing or background processing in `phonegap`. I want some solution that can work on iPhone and android. I'm beginner of `phonegap` and don't have much knowledge.
But I've come to know about using the plugins to use with native code.
But I don't want to use anything native, I want to accomplish the task using `javascript/phonegap/html` so the solution works on all supported platforms.
I've tried webworkers but it seems that these are not supported.
Can anybody share their experience in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Native is the only fully compatible approach. There might be phonegap plugins already available for what you need.

Web Workers are supported in android since 4.4 KitKat, and in iOS since v5.0.

Source:
http://caniuse.com/#search=webworkers

But be aware only thread-safe components of the DOM are available in a WebWorker. Hence you can't use libraries like jQuery there (at least not the standard release, there might be some stripped-down versions though).

Prior to that, you could use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, but that code would run in foreground and will make the GUI unresponsive if you hog the main thread for too long.